# restrict pidof to own processes

Tags: bash, process, pid

In bash,

```
pidof unison
```

will list me unison processes of all users. However I am only interested in instances started under my uid.

How can I achieve this?

What I want to do:
I'm periodically syncing several accounts on several machines using unison. However, I want the sync to not start, if the current user has manually started unison.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use `pgrep` instead, like

```
pgrep -u <userid> unison
```

which will return a list of pids of unison processes that have the euid of the given user.

Comment: Note that if there are any other processes with names that contain "unison", you may need to force an _exact_ match using the `-x` argument to `pgrep`. (For instance, `pgrep -u ferd gvfsd` returns 9 PIDs on my system, while `pgrep -xu ferd gvfsd` matches only one.) This is different from `pidof`, which performs an exact match by default.

Answer (score 1):

You can parse `ps` output like this:

`ps -ef | grep unison | grep -v grep | grep "${USER}" | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: this works, but Eric's solution is a bit more handy.